# <head> files disappearing from template

Tags: templates, css

I have a site (link below), that every now and again, a bunch of the CSS of JS links in the head, simply disappear from the template (when i view source, they are not there). this of course means that the site loads with very partial design and layout.

The issue is that its intermittent - it happens and then 'fixes' itself without us even doing anything...

At one point I thought it might be a cache issue, so I disabled (and deleted) the cache, but its still happening.

Has anything run into anything like this before?

Link: `http://yadezra.org.il/` (maybe during a visit to the site it will happen to be during an occurrence of the issue).

Comment: *The client of course is very antsy..*. That really is your problem, and not ours. What happens between you and your client is between you and your client. Also, why post links if you don't want it hotlinked?

Comment: @PieterGoosen - point taken - simply edit that comment out, not need to come on so strong. Go get yourself a Castle and them come back ;)
regarding the link - as i now mentioned, i am hoping that someone might try help, visit the site during such an occurrence and see what i mean - but i don't want the link followed by SE's.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.

This is because a lot of your file request are getting a 4XX, 5XX response or can't be loaded.

[image]

I started looking further and realized some of your js/css is being loaded properly.  However some of it is not. The files that are not being loaded have a :443 extension to them.

```
www.yadezra.org.il:443/wp-content/themes/gorising/js/jquery.downCount.js?ver=4.3.1
```

However this works fine and is what you should be loading

```
www.yadezra.org.il/wp-content/themes/gorising/js/jquery.downCount.js?ver=4.3.1
```

You will need to figure out why :443 is being added and how you can get rid of it.  I suggest deactivating all your plugins and using process of elimination to see one of them is causing the issue.

If it is not a plugin you should check out your http/https configuration and your .htaccess files.   Ask your host if your not familiar with servers or have someone assist.

If all that fails it could very well be a theme issue.  I did some research on the theme and noticed people complaining about loading issues for over a year and it doesn't have the best ratings.

You can use pingdom.com to see some more detailed information about files being loaded like I did in the screenshot above.

Comment: Thanks so much - i will delve into the info you provided!

Comment: @kneidels Whats the status on your testing as per this solution?

Comment: Ok great @kneidels please let everyone know how it goes :)

Comment: you are definitely right it seems... i haven't figured out where the 443 comes from yet...but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Keep looking or have someone more experienced take a look. I think there is a good chance it could do with your http/https/ssl settings.  443 is port number for https just incase you didn't know, figured I would state that as it may be helpful.

Comment: @kneidels see you fixed it, what was the issue?

Comment: @JediTricks007 - turned out to be something in thew htaccess file i think. some https redirect issue. a big mess. thanks again!